# Bluemix ,Running Locally

Tags: local, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I would like to know if there is a way to run bluemix locally on the computer by using the app that I created on bluemix(In the site), I would want to know if I can use that app directly or would I have to use the cloud foundry for this purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the apps built for Bluemix can also be run or tested locally. Here is the [link to a small app for Bluemix](https://github.com/data-henrik/db2visitors/blob/master/app.js) that checks whether it is local or on Bluemix. The key is that the app needs to be prepared for it.

If you want to run a Cloud Foundry app entirely "locally" on the computers in your data center or on your machine, and deploy to there in the same way you deploy the app to Bluemix, then you would need Cloud Foundry on that machine. IBM is offering "[Bluemix Local](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html)" exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question has been answered and marked as valid I can notice is somehow wrong.

1. All apps in bluemix can be downloaded and run it locally. Go to the left column in your app dashboard and click on "start coding". That section will give you instructions on how to run your app locally.
2. Bluemix Local is not meant to be run locally in your own machine. Please check the [requirements](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html#localinfra) and let me know if your machine has those specs

Answer (score 0):

Running a Bluemix app locally is definitely possible and can be a time-saver during development. There are three parts to running an app locally:

1. Get the source code available locally (easy if you're using git or equivalent) and build it.
2. Ensure the platform dependencies are available locally. For most cases, this is just a case of downloading a suitable runtime (WebSphere Liberty, Node.js, Ruby, etc).
3. Ensure access to dependent services. If you wanted a completely offline mode, this would mean standing up local copies of services. For databases this is a bit of a nuisance and for some of the other services, like the Watson ones, this is more or less impossible. They could be stubbed out instead, but usually (in my experience) the reason to run locally is to quickly test the effect of code changes, which means keeping the service context as similar as possible to what's on Bluemix. If you export a VCAP_SERVICES environment variable with the same credentials which are exposed to your Bluemix app, you will have behaviour parity locally and on the platform. [My team](http://garage.mybluemix.net/posts/running-locally/) usually uses a [generateSecrets](http://garage.mybluemix.net/posts/running-locally/generateSecrets) script to read `cf env` and create a `.secrets` file. We then run `. .secrets` in the terminal which launches the server.